# Razor pages only model binding on first load - not binding on reloads

Tags: razor-pages

I have a Razor page with a form that only works on the first load after starting the application, but on any subsequent requests the form values are empty and not bound.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your OnGet method is forced to return a Page instead of void.

Change

```
public async void OnGet()
{
    your code here
}
```

to

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
{
    your code here

    return Page();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `async` handler methods return a `Task` instead of `void`.

Change

```
public async void OnGet()
{
    your code here
}
```

to

```
public async Task OnGet()
{
    your code here
}
```

It's fine for non-async handlers to return `void`.